# Accessing Data attribute of html input control in MVC2 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am submiiting a form from view which contains input field with specific data attribute

```
<form>
<input type="text" data-user="001" name="mytext" />
</form>
```

this from is submitted to a controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Settings(FormCollection formValues)
        {
//here i can access input control's value by its name like
string user= formValues["mytext"];
}
```

but how i can get value of data-user attribute in controller?

Comment: You cannot. A form only submits name/value pairs corresponding to the `name` and `value` attributes of form controls.

Comment: You can do it using javascript. You should add hidden inputs to your form on submit.

Comment: you have to use hidden field data- attributes will not be posted in form

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do it. You can access session variable from controller like this, however:

```
string strsetting1 = (string)HttpContext.Session["setting1"];
```

In your `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void session_start()
{
    Session["setting1"] = "Y";
}
```